# cookies with golang and gorilla/csrf

Tags: go, cookies, gorilla

I am new to Go and trying to build a web site signup/login.

I was doing session cookies like this:

```
 // If the login succeeded
    cookie:=&http.Cookie{
            Name: "session",
            Value: uuid.NewV4().String(),
        }
        sessionStore[cookie.Value] = Client{true,databaseUsername}
        http.SetCookie(res, cookie)
        http.Redirect(res, req, "/home", 302)
```

But after adding CSRF protection using gorilla/csrf my session cookie is not working.

any thought?